# Passing an expression to the Plot Function does not Work

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, expression-manipulation, rule

Solving a differential equation I found that its solution was analytic, and I stored it as an expression from the default rule output of the `DSolve[]` function:

`soleq2 = y[x] /. soleq2[[1, 1]]`

Which has output:

`Sqrt[x] BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, x] C[1] + Sqrt[x] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, x] C[2]`

I then plotted this:

`Manipulate[Plot[soleq2, {x, 0, 10}], {C[1], 0, 10}, {C[2], 0, 10}]`

but the plot does not show anything, only the sliders for the modulation of `C[1]` and `C[2]`. I tried substituting these constants with other letters thinking their format might interfere with the kernel, but to no avail.

Comment: See the "Possible Issues" section of the documentation for [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) where it explains that, and gives an example for, **Manipulate only "notices" explicit visible parameters**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your control variables are not local to Manipulate. One way around it is

```
soleq2 = Sqrt[x] BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, x] C[1] + 
   Sqrt[x] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, x] C[2];
Manipulate[
 Plot[soleq2 /. {C[1] -> c[1], C[2] -> c[2]}, {x, 0, 10}],
 {c[1], 0, 10},
 {c[2], 0, 10},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c[1], c[2]}
 ]
```

[image]

Or you could move the expression inside Manipulate, so it "sees" `C[1]` and `C[2]`

```
Manipulate[
soleq2=Sqrt[x] BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2,x] C[1]+Sqrt[x] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2,x] C[2];
Plot[soleq2,{x,0,10}],
{C[1],0,10},
{C[2],0,10},
TrackedSymbols:>{C[1],C[2]}
]
```